# Markov Logic Networks: where to find a thorough mathematical treatment?

Tags: probability-theory, first-order-logic, markov-process

all. I am looking for a thorough mathematical treatment of Markov Logic Networks. I would like explicit formal proof of how exactly from a set of weighted constraints you actually get to a graph structure where the nodes are the ground atoms. I have the intuition of it and a sketch proof of my own, but I really would love an actual academic reference for it.